# Using Goto Function in two function

Tags: c, function, goto

I have 2 functions in my code, namely `void compare(...)` and `void checklist(...)`.

In `void compare(...)`, I have `if` statement that has been defined as `Reselection`.

Now, I need to use the `goto` function from `void checklist(...)` to go to `Reselection` in `void compare(...)`.

Since I know that the `goto` function can only be used within that function, I was wondering if there are other function that works as `goto` function but can be used in different `void` functions?

Comment: why don't you just call the other function? goto is horrible , don't use it.

Comment: That sounds like you design is overly complicated. Generally, `goto` should not be used lightly. Aside from that, I can't say I quite understand what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, labels are local to the function in which they are defined. And programs would be a real mess otherwise.

You should make `Reselection` a function of its own.